# When does the Caligni Slayer's Soul Harvest trigger?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

The [Caligni Slayer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=577) has the following ability:

> Soul Harvest (necromancy) The caligni slayer deals an additional 2d6 negative damage to flat-footed creatures.

It seems to work like Sneak Attack, except with a different type of damage, but when exactly does it trigger? Would it trigger on someone targeted by this caligni's Phantom Pain? (assuming said Caligni is hidden in the darkness, or the target is prone, or whatever other situation that would make them flat-footed) Would it trigger on that spell's persistent damage? On Death Implosion's damage?

Answer (score 4):

### There is no condition on the nature of the damage source

Since the text you cite above is the entire text of the ability, there are no additional restrictions or conditions on the kind of damage source or effect this applies to. The only condition is that the creature is flat-footed when it takes damage from an effect caused by the slayer.

So this would apply to its melee attacks, as well as to its damage dealing spells.

Compare this to the wording of Sneak Attack:

> If you **Strike** a creature that has the flat-footed condition **with an agile or finesse melee weapon, an agile or finesse unarmed attack, a ranged weapon attack, or a ranged unarmed attack**, you deal an extra 1d6 precision damage

Here, additional limiting conditions on what you can deal damage with are spelled out.

I'm not sure about the death implosion -- at that point the Calini Slayer supposedly is dead, but given that the explosion itself is still an ability, so I think it would apply to that damage too, if a creature in the blast radius was flat-footed.

Comment: would it also trigger on black smear poison damage?

Comment: @AnneAunyme I suspect it is the poison, not the slayer dealing that damage, so no.

Comment: One could say the same for the spell : this dude casted the spell, indeed, but the same way they used the poison.

Comment: Yeah, the question is there if you are dealing damage with the spell, like you with a sword when you attack, or if the spell or weapon does it. But I think there is a difference: the poison deals damage by itself when interacted with. The slayer would not even need to be there.

Comment: The same could be said for the persistent effects of the spell: it doesn't rely on the caster to actively maintain it.